# Old App Version Being Released In Play Store While New Update Is In Review

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We have an Android app in the Google Play Store. We just uploaded and submitted v2.2.1 for review. Our App Listing page now shows v2.2.0 Rollout Halted, versions 2.0.9 thru 2.1.9 Release Not Live, and v2.0.8 Available On Google Play. See attached images. We just downloaded our app from Google Play and confirmed it is sending v2.0.8!

Why is v2.0.8 being released while v2.2.1 is in review and not any of the latest versions like v2.2.0 or v2.1.9? What should we do to fix?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using managed publishing by any chance?

Comment: Did changing to managed publishing help @JBeesky ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by user14678216, you need to turn Managed Publishing on in the Google Play Console.

[image]

[image]